# Date difference in mvc view with current date / sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor

I get date from my model and it is displayed in view

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UpdateDate)
```

UpdateDate is datetime.(Format 2017-01-12 17:16:32.013)

What I want to do is, compare it with current date and show difference in time.

- If the difference between current datetime and UpdatedDate is less
  than 60 min then it should say "'X' Minues ago" (where 'X' is
  difference in minutes)
- If the difference between current datetime and UpdatedDate is more
  than 60 min and less than 24 hours then it should say " 'Y' Hours 'X'
  Minues ago" (where 'X' is difference in minutes and 'Y' is hours)
- If the difference between current datetime and UpdatedDate is more than 24 hours then it should say " 'Z' days 'Y' Hours 'X' Minues ago" (where 'X' is difference in minutes and 'Y' is hours and 'Z' is days)

I want to do this in view. Your help is really appreciated.

Thanks

---

Here is how I am doing this,

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - DateTime1;
string formatted = string.Format(
                       CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                       "{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes, {3} seconds", 
                       diff.Days, 
                       diff.Hours, 
                       diff.Minutes, 
                       diff.Seconds);


This works but it will prroduce o/p like
0 days 2 hours 28min (o/p needs to be 2 hours 28min) 
or
0 days 0 hours 33 min   ( o/p needs to be 33 min)
```

How do I enhance this without putting if else to check for '0' and get expected output

---

Well can we write a user defined function in sql server for desired format?

Comment: [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer#humanize-datetime) could be a possible solution for you.  It's a NuGet package that does this sort of thing out of the box.

Comment: Well I will check this. Can't I do this simply with razor? Thanks.

Comment: You could create a public string UpdateDateText property, and within it, check the date difference yourself and produce a string with the time difference.  Nothing in-built to do this; you would have to set it up yourself.

Comment: The view is the wrong place! You better put that logic into your controller and calculate the time differences there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create FUNCTION GetDateDiff
(
@a datetime
)
RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Return varchar(100) 
Set @Return = '';
if(Convert(int,(DATEDIFF(day, @a, getdate()))) >= 1)
Begin
    Set @Return += Convert(varchar(10),(DATEDIFF(day, @a, getdate()))) + ' Day ';
End
if(Convert(int,(DATEDIFF(HOUR, @a, getdate()))) >= 1)
Begin
    Set @Return += Convert(varchar(10),(DATEDIFF(HOUR, @a, getdate()))) + ' Hour ';
End
if(Convert(int,(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @a, getdate()))) >= 1)
Begin
    Set @Return += Convert(varchar(10),(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @a, getdate()))) + ' Minute ';
End


return @Return
END
```

So I am writing this function in sql, any suggestions on improvement?
Further when day difference in greater than 1, the string should be 'days' (same for hours and minutes)